# JSTL with response.sendRedirect

Tags: jsp, servlets, request, jstl

Why is that jstl is not working(blank results) with

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

and jstl is working with

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
```

EDIT: in my jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.(List from servlet)}" var="s">
<h1><c:out value="${s.(variable from list)}"></c:out></h1>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Define "not working". You realize that all the attributes store in the request are lost after a redirect, right?

Comment: not working = i mean the list is empty that is saved in request.setAttribute("key",list object); if redirect it is empty and if i use the dispatcher the list is populated.

Comment: is it better to use dispatcher than redirect? because if dispatcher the url of the servlet is being used not the jsp page eg. "page.jsp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to understand what a redirect is. A redirect consist in sending a response to the browser telling it to send a new GET request to a given URL. So obviously, the attributes you stored in the request before the `sendRedirect()` call are not available anymore when the JSP is executed, since it's executed as a response to another, different HTTP request.

A redirect is typically used as part as the [redirect-after-post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. Otherwise, if you simply want to dispatch to a JSP to generate the HTML markup that consitutes the response to a request, a forward is what you need.

Comment: like my comment above is it better to use the dispatcher than redirect?because with dispatcher the url of servlet is being used.

Comment: Read my edited answer. It's perfectly normal to see the URL of the servlet in the browser, since it's the URL where the request is sent by the browser.

Comment: i have this scenario in my webpage i have a div
    <div id='result>
and when i click a button another jsp file will be loaded to result.
is there any way that i can access the attribute saved in request from the new loaded jsp file?

Comment: No. Request attributes only exist for the request. Not for subsequent ones. Your AJAX request should send the necessary values, or the sqerver should get them again from the database.

Comment: when i reload or refresh the page do the request scope or JSTL refresh too? eg(servletname?showmainpage=true then in servlet i have if(request.getParameter("showmainpage")!=null){
String test="a";}
request.setAttribute("test",test);
request.getRequestDispatcher("address").forward(request,response);
}

Comment: @JBNizet does the functionality remains same for the `session` objects with `sendRedirect()`

Comment: @sankrish attributes stored in the session are accessible by all subsequent requests, if that's what you ask. Make sure to use http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: So i could access the `session` attributes in the subsequent pages , if i my session is valid . this is same for both redirect and requestdispatcher . am i correct with my understanding?

Comment: @sankrish yes, you are.